# atomic fetch_add vs add performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

The code below demonstrates curiosities of multi-threaded programming. In particular the performance of `std::memory_order_relaxed` increment vs regular increment in a single thread. What I do not understand why fetch_add(relaxed) single-threaded is twice slower than a regular increment.

```
static void BM_IncrementCounterLocal(benchmark::State& state) {
  volatile std::atomic_int val2;

  while (state.KeepRunning()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      DoNotOptimize(val2.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed));
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_IncrementCounterLocal)->ThreadRange(1, 8);

static void BM_IncrementCounterLocalInt(benchmark::State& state) {
  volatile int val3 = 0;

  while (state.KeepRunning()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      DoNotOptimize(++val3);
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_IncrementCounterLocalInt)->ThreadRange(1, 8);
```

Output:

```
      Benchmark                               Time(ns)    CPU(ns) Iterations
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------
      BM_IncrementCounterLocal/threads:1            59         60   11402509                                 
      BM_IncrementCounterLocal/threads:2            30         61   11284498                                 
      BM_IncrementCounterLocal/threads:4            19         62   11373100                                 
      BM_IncrementCounterLocal/threads:8            17         62   10491608

      BM_IncrementCounterLocalInt/threads:1         31         31   22592452                                 
      BM_IncrementCounterLocalInt/threads:2         15         31   22170842                                 
      BM_IncrementCounterLocalInt/threads:4          8         31   22214640                                 
      BM_IncrementCounterLocalInt/threads:8          9         31   21889704
```

Comment: Have you compared the machine code?

Comment: You have to tell the compiler that you're in single threaded mode.

Comment: Are you on a system where `memory_order_relaxed` does anything? On an x86 it doesn't. `fetch_add` will likely issue a bus lock to make the add operation atomic. `operator++` does not need to do that.

Comment: lock prefixed instruction(if you're using x86_64) takes comparably longer time than simply adding instruction. The cost is unavoidable for ensuring the atomicity.

Answer (score 2):

With the `volatile int`, the compiler must ensure that it does not optimize away and/or reorder any reads/writes of the variable.

With the `fetch_add`, the *CPU* must take precautions that the read-modify-write operation is atomic.

These are two completely different requirements: The atomicity requirement means that the CPU has to communicate with other CPUs on your machine, ensuring that they don't read/write the given memory location between its own read and write. If the compiler compiles the `fetch_add` using a compare-and-swap instruction, it will actually emit a short loop to catch the case that some other CPU modified the value in between.

For the `volatile int` no such communication is necessary. On the contrary, `volatile` requires that the compiler does not invent any reads: `volatile` was designed for single thread communication with hardware registers, where the mere act of reading the value may have side effects.

Comment: I used std::memory_order_relaxed so no memory barriers are put and I was under impression that on intel processors word increments are atomic as is.
fetch_add and CAS are different operations.

Comment: Why should word increments be atomic as is? The CPU has to first fetch the current value from memory, then to modify it, then to store it back. Any atomicity constraint on this requires significant additional effort. The CPU is even allowed to reorder both the read and the write with other memory operations as it pleases, as long as the *single thread* results remain the same. Specialized atomic instructions have been added to the instruction set specifically to allow for atomic `fetch_add` operation etc. The only thing that's naturally atomic is a single aligned write or read.

Answer (score 0):

The local version is not using atomics.  (The fact it is using `volatile` is a red herring - `volatile` has essentially no meaning in multi-threaded code).

The atomic version *is* using atomics (!).  The fact that only one thread is actually going to be use accessing the variable is invisible to the CPU, and I'm not surprised the compiler hasn't spotted it either.  (There's no point wasting developer effort figuring out if it is safe to turn `std::atomic_int` into `int`, when it almost never will be.  Nobody will write `atomic_int` if they don't need to access it from multiple threads.)

As such, the atomic version will go to the trouble of making sure the increment actually is atomic, and frankly, I'm surprised that is only 2x slower - I would have expected more like 10x.

Comment: I asked why fetch_add is slower than regular increment. I think you answered something else :)

Comment: "the atomic version will go to the trouble of making sure the increment actually is atomic".  `memory_order_relaxed` says "There are no synchronization or ordering constraints, only atomicity is required of this operation."  Depending on your processor (x86 for example) this can be as expensive as any other memory order.